# Why does the series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^∞ \frac{k}{k^2 + 1} $ diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Why does $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \Re\mathopen{} \left(\frac{k-i}{k^2 + 1}\right)\mathclose{}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k}{k^2 + 1}  $ diverge?

How should I go about approaching this problem?

Comment: I would try first multiplying the fraction by the conjugate: k + i

Comment: I tried it. still not sure why the real part diverges.

Comment: The partial sum up to $n$ of the real parts is $\sum_1^n \frac{k}{k^2+1}$. This is $\ge \sum_1^n \frac{k}{2k^2}$. But we know that the harmonic series $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{k}$ diverges.

Comment: $Re \left(\frac{k-i}{k^2 + 1}\right)=\frac{k}{k^2 + 1}>\frac{1}{2k}$ for $k>1.$

Answer (score 7):

We have

$$\text{Re}\mathopen{}\left(\frac{k+i}{k^2+1}\right)\mathclose{}=\frac{k}{k^2+1}\ge\frac1{2k}$$

and the harmonic series diverges.

Comment: @alex.jordan I was unable to gauge the edits. What was edited?  And thank you!

Comment: Nothing serious, just LaTeX niceness. When you have an something like `\text{Re}`, and you follow with a `\left(`, there is an unsightly extra gap of space. A hackish way to fix this is to introduce negative space. Instead, I put `\mathopen{}` before the `\left(` and then put a matching `\mathclose{}` after the `\right)`, which has the desired effect. You can see the gap in the other answer, where they used `\Re` instead of `\text{Re}`. There is a gap between their `\Re` and their `\left(`.

Comment: Also, instead of `\text{Re}`, the "proper" thing to do is to use `\operatorname{Re}`. Or you can put `\DeclareMathOperator}{\myRe}{Re}` somewhere, and then use `\myRe` as you please. Just note that doing this latter thing could potentially effect other answers on the same page, if they have defined `\myRe` for some reason.

Comment: @alex.jordan Very much appreciate the tips!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{array}\\
\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \Re \left(\frac{k-i}{k^2 + 1}\right)
&=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \Re \left(\frac{k}{k^2 + 1}\right)
+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \Re \left(\frac{-i}{k^2 + 1}\right)\\
&=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{k^2 + 1}\\
\text{so}\\
\big|\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \Re \left(\frac{k-i}{k^2 + 1}\right)\big|
&=\big|\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{k^2 + 1}\big|\\
&>\big|\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{k^2}\big|\\
&>\big|\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\big|\\
\end{array}
$

and this last sum diverges.